# Speech to Text apps stop after a few words

Tags: voice-recognition

I am trying out a few Speech to Text apps. All of them don't perform as I need them to. I have several pages of text, but I get no further than a half a sentence before the app stops. It records what I am saying, but just stops.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try calibrating your talk to 51st in the settings menue. It will have you repeat a few words a couple times until it has full voice recognition.

Comment: Talk to txt..basically go to voice recognition.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "51st". Looking under Language & Input > Speech > Voice Input, I see nothing of the sort.

Answer (score 1):

I have an old Galaxy Lite with the same problem: the microphone would cut off after a few words. Finally, I opened the Google app, opened the menu (on mine it's at the bottom right labeled "more"), then Settings> Voice> "OK Google" detection> then under "OK Google" Voice Model, tap "Retrain voice model" and follow the prompts. That worked for me. I'm not sure how newer versions of Android get there, but the goal is to get the Google app to retrain to recognize your voice. Good Luck.